# Cannot resolve module 'react-redux/lib/components/connect'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am updating my project to the latest version of `react, react-redux, react-dom, etc`, and I encountered the following error:

```
ERROR in ./app/components/Modules/AdsBanner/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-redux/lib/components/connect' in /home/cpt/Desktop/prod/local/app/components/Modules/AdsBanner
 @ ./app/components/Modules/AdsBanner/index.js 51:15-60
```

Here is the part of the code where the conflict comes from:

```
import connect from 'react-redux/lib/components/connect';
//some code
export default connect(({regular}) => ({regular}))(AdBanner);
```

Can you please tell whether it is worth rolling back to the previous version of `react-redux`, or rewrite this part of the code? Unfortunately, I did not find similar information anywhere. Thanks so much for any advice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

connect is from react-redux right so we have to import like `import { connect } from 'react-redux';` once try it may useful to you.